# How can I config vim to show me value of a variable / const?

Tags: plugin-coc

I have a vim configuration with `COC` installed where I can `gd` to jump to a definition.
How can I config it, so it will, upon hovering on the word (with cursor, not mouse), will do the following:

1. if is variabe / const:
2. go to definition
3. check the value of definition
4. show on a small popup

Is this possible? Is there a plugin for this already?

Comment: If you configure `include`/`includeexpr` and `define`, you can use `[d`/`]d`. Then there's also `:help CursorHold-example` if you have tags. With ALE, an autocommand that does `:ALEHover` might work if the lang-server supports it.

Comment: I actually have ALE installed, but `ALEHover` did nothing for me when I tried it. Don't know `include / includeexpr / define`